# install the drivers for the built in blueray /dvd drive and other such hardware on my laptop?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, software-installation

If I install ubuntu will I need to install the drivers for the built in blueray /dvd drive and other such hardware on my laptop?

Comment: Install the drivers to do what precisely? Use the drive? Or play movies?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *other such hardware*?

Comment: The laptop has a bluray player and a dvd burner. To be honest I dont use them hardly ever but still want them to work it i install ubuntu. I don't have any and software with the laptop. no windows cd or drivers cd

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking, I'm pretty sure there is no blu-ray player for ubuntu but your dvds should work with `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: Ok Thanks as long as i can play dvd's and burn dvd's thats all i need. I might come back to you for help if I need it after I have installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Playback should be supported for most DVD types by enabling the ubuntu-restricted-extras package.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

You may also need to install libdvdcss.

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
 sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```